# How to indicate an android tablet is actively charging with LED?

Tags: voltage, led, capacitor, charging

I am a rank beginner, and I do feel like I am missing something pretty obvious here, as the problem doesn't *seem* that complex. (I know... famous last words)

**Problem:**

- Android tablet (in a *completely* proprietary setup) charging within a rack.
- Charging connector is a little flaky, and I need an indicator when a good connection has been made, and charging is happening.
- 5 V 2 A power supply dedicated to each tablet, can be modified (meaning: can cut the wires, can wire a circuit inline). Getting a more powerful power supply is not an option.

Voltage coming our of the power supply is approximately 5.2 V, amperage varies depending on the test, maxing out at about 1.2 A.

I'm not messing with the charging connector at all. I'm modifying the wire coming from the power supply itself, and wiring the various solutions in along the ground line (black wire).

**What I have tried:**

- Take the direct approach... just wire an LED and a resistor inline, so that when the circuit is complete, the tablet is charging. This doesn't work, as (I'm assuming) the voltage drop of the LED (tried several different colors) is too large to allow the tablet to charge when the LED is lit.
- Make a slightly more complex circuit, with a capacitor inline, and the LED wired in parallel with the capacitor. I was hoping this would mitigate the voltage drop, but this does not seem to work at all. It is certainly *possible* that is is a workable approach, and I wired it incorrectly.

**What I need:**

- to know if there is a complete circuit, and if so, light the LED
- the tablet needs to be able to successfully charge (we can determine this in testing, don't need to know this in the finished solution)

I'm not asking anyone to design the solution for me... just point me in the right direction. Every attempt so far either results in no connection at all, as if the circuit is not complete, or a complete circuit, but the tablet does not indicate that it is charging (again I'm assuming that this is the problem).

Any guidance?

Comment: A current shunt (small value resistor) to allow measuring current and a circuit that lights a LED when a certain minimum amount of current is being drawn.

Comment: A usb voltage/current meter as a cheap commercial product on fleabay and the like. Theres even multi port usb power supplies with individual voltage and current indicators of various quality. Or are you trying to do anything except a visual check? Even if the tablet isn't charging at a high rate your going to see a voltage on it.

Comment: @Unimportant So far in our testing, any voltage drop affects the ability of the tablet to charge. Is it possible to power an LED when current is present without accompanying voltage drop to the main circuit?

Comment: @mmc - the tests you've described so far indicate that you've had relatively large voltage drops in line with the USB supply - probably in the order of 1.5V or more, depending on the LED you use. The shunt resistor proposed by Unimportant would create a much smaller voltage drop - in the order of 10's to maybe a few 100's of mV, and as such would not interrupt charging in the way your experiments have done.

Comment: A small shunt that drops in the order of 50 to 100 mV will have no effect, that's within normal voltage margins. You'll need to amplify the measured voltage across the shunt to make it useful, with a opamp for example.

Comment: @mmc a inline resistor and led or inline capacitor, are significantly different than a shunt resistor. An inline led resistor limited to 20mA will prevent the tablet from working, while a shunt resistor will be basically invisible to the tablet like the non 0 resistance of copper wires that run to the tablet.